# How to keep "remember" Checkbox choice when page reload using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am new to ajax. 
I am using ajax and jsp to retrieve data from database. 
When new data inserted into the database the new data will be displayed automatically in the Jsp page.So in the ajax code I set the `Timeout()`.
In the jsp page against every data row there is a checkbox. If I check the checkbox the checkbox is changed when the page is reload. But I want to remain unchanged the checkbox when the page is reloaded...

```
<html>
<body onload="Ajax()">

<script type="text/javascript">


function Ajax()
{
    var xmlHttp;

        try
        {   
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
                {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); //       Internet Explorer
                }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
                {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("No AJAX!?");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
        {
                   document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET","ajaxCalled.jsp",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

}
```

Default text

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  import="dbbean.DBBean,java.sql.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkboxCheck()
{
var checkbox1=document.getElementsById("checkbox0")

if(checkbox1.checked)
    {
    alert(checkbox1);
    checkbox1.checked="true";


    }
else
    {
    alert(checkbox1);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="checkboxCheck()">



        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10>
            <tr>
                <th>checkbox</th>

<%
    DBBean db=new DBBean();
    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    int count=0;
    String checkName="checkbox";
    String checkbox1="";
    try
    {
        con=db.getDBConnection();
        rs=db.execSQL("select * from login_history");
%>                  


                <th>user_id</th>
                <th>ip_address</th>
                <th>login_status</th>
            </tr>

    <%
        while(rs.next())
        {
            checkbox1=checkName+count;
            count++;
            out.println(checkbox1);
        %>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="<%= checkbox1 %>"  ></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td>
        </tr>

<%
    /* out.println(rs.getString(1));
    out.println(rs.getString(2));
    out.println(rs.getString(3));
    out.println("</br></br>");*/    
    }
%>

    </table>
<%
    rs.close();
    con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>

<div id="disp" style="visibility:hidden">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i assume you are using servlet if so; then save the choice value on **request set attribute** and assign it when returning to your page reload e.g `request.setAttribute("attributeName",attributeValue);` [Set Attributes in a Servlet Request](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15433) and retrieve it by Expression Language directly in jsp or by javascript manipulation

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using servlet if so; 
then save the choice value on request set attribute and assign 
it when returning to your page reload e.g :

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",attributeValue);
```

Set Attributes in a Servlet Request and retrieve it by Expression Language **EL** directly in jsp or by **javascript** manipulation